# Parse.Query.Exclude() function not excluding the given values

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am trying to write cloud code that excludes certain values from a query. I have tried using both `select()` and `exclude()` to limit what values come back in a query. Here is what my code looks like

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeFind(Parse.User, (request) => {
     return request.query.select('email');
});
```

For reference, here is the curl command that I am using to test my cloud code:

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://<parse-server>.b4a.io/parse/users' \
--header 'X-Parse-Application-Id: <app-id>' \
--header 'X-Parse-REST-API-Key: <api-key>' \
--header 'X-Parse-Session-Token: <token>'
```

---

In theory, the response to this command should look something like this:

```
{
results:[{'email':'123@example.com'},{'email':'456@example.com'}']
}
```

---

Instead what I get is the following(all of the user information I would normally get if I did nothing):

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "objectId": "jKXYLgeB6x",
            "username": "cperryoh",
            "email": "123@example.com",
            "isBanned": false,
            "emailVerified": true,
            "createdAt": "2022-07-25T17:09:37.963Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-07-27T16:34:54.186Z",
            "chunksOwned": {
                "__type": "Relation",
                "className": "chunk"
            },
            "ACL": {
                "jKXYLgeB6x": {
                    "read": true,
                    "write": true
                },
                "*": {
                    "read": true
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "objectId": "ykJJhvNuPh",
            "username": "testUser",
            "email":"456@example.com"
            "isBanned": false,
            "emailVerified": true,
            "createdAt": "2022-07-25T19:39:02.854Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-07-27T16:20:48.083Z",
            "chunksOwned": {
                "__type": "Relation",
                "className": "chunk"
            },
            "ACL": {
                "*": {
                    "read": true
                },
                "ykJJhvNuPh": {
                    "read": true,
                    "write": true
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

---

To further add to the confusion, in the cloud-code/parse-SDK [documentation](https://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/master/Parse.Query.html), there is no reference to the beforeFind trigger. So I am not even sure what the return type of lambda/function is supposed to be. The only thing I have that is telling me I can return a query object is an example in the cloud code guide [here](https://docs.parseplatform.org/cloudcode/guide/#examples-1). In one of the examples, they return the result of `Parse.Query.or()` which does return an object of type Query. Am I using `.select()` incorrectly or is it not meant for what I am trying to do? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try just:

```js
Parse.Cloud.beforeFind(Parse.User, (request) => {
     request.query.select('email');
});
```